# Missing Connected Services in class project in VS2022 17.2.1

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently updated to the latest version of Visual Studio 2022 (17.2.1) and now I'm missing the "Update Connected Services" button. Also tried to add a brand new class project. With this I wasn't even able to add a connected service in the first place. Am I overlooking something? I would like to update my connected service.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

They moved the Update options into the Add Connected Service dialog a while back. You can find it by right-clicking on the project `Add->Connected service...`

Unfortunately, it seems the Configure link in that dialog is broken as of v17.2. There is no way to re-configure an existing connected service at the moment, as far as I can tell.

**Update**
MS fixed the update functionality in VS 2022 17.4